# In JavaScript, I want to hover over a radio button and have it output the value of that radio button?

Tags: radio-button, paragraph

I hover over the button and it hopefully outputs the value of the radio button into a paragraph below. I tried the below code but it's not working. I was hoping 'this' as the ID would mean the ID of what element activated the event.

```
function showDegree() {

    var classInput = document.getElementById(this).value;

    document.getElementById('classOutput').innerHTML = classInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted code, "this" refers to the current scope, which would be the function showDegree.  If you want to have a reference back to the element that threw the event:

Try this:

```
function showDegree(evt) {
    var event  = window.event || evt;
    var source = event.target || event.srcElement;

    document.getElementById('classOutput').innerHTML = source.value;
}
```

Then your event listener can be called like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="degree" value="some value" onmouseover="showDegree(event)" />
```